# Filled area graph vertical orientation

Tags: vega

I am attempting to get a vertical filled area graph, where the area on the left between the y axis and the data line is filled. Essentially, take the normal area graph and rotate it 90 degrees clockwise.

I've basically just taken the example from the vega examples and tried to convert everything to vertical, changed the names of the scales to something more related to the data, and added a line width and colour.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "padding": 5,

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "interpolate",
      "value": "linear",
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": [
          "basis",
          "cardinal",
          "catmull-rom",
          "linear",
          "monotone",
          "natural",
          "step",
          "step-after",
          "step-before"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"u": 1,  "v": 28}, {"u": 2,  "v": 55},
        {"u": 3,  "v": 43}, {"u": 4,  "v": 91},
        {"u": 5,  "v": 81}, {"u": 6,  "v": 53},
        {"u": 7,  "v": 19}, {"u": 8,  "v": 87},
        {"u": 9,  "v": 52}, {"u": 10, "v": 48},
        {"u": 11, "v": 24}, {"u": 12, "v": 49},
        {"u": 13, "v": 87}, {"u": 14, "v": 66},
        {"u": 15, "v": 17}, {"u": 16, "v": 27},
        {"u": 17, "v": 68}, {"u": 18, "v": 16},
        {"u": 19, "v": 49}, {"u": 20, "v": 15}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "uscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "u"}
    },
    {
      "name": "vscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "v"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "vscale", "tickCount": 25},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "uscale"}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "area",
      "orient": "horizontal",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "vscale", "field": "v"},
          "y": {"scale": "uscale", "field": "u"},
          "x2": {"scale": "vscale", "value": 0},
          "stroke": {"value": "#000000"},
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "update": {
          "interpolate": {"signal": "interpolate"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here. According to the docs "vertical" orientation is the default, and I've tried this with x2 and y2, and orient "vertical" and "horizontal" for both - I've also tried to set the scale as vscale and uscale for x2 and y2.

I get no errors in the vega online editor - The line is correct but I would expect the graph to be filled to the left of the line between the y axis and the graph line. The actual output right now is just a solid line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `orient` property has to go into the encode block.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "padding": 5,

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "interpolate",
      "value": "linear",
      "bind": {
        "input": "select",
        "options": [
          "basis",
          "cardinal",
          "catmull-rom",
          "linear",
          "monotone",
          "natural",
          "step",
          "step-after",
          "step-before"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"u": 1,  "v": 28}, {"u": 2,  "v": 55},
        {"u": 3,  "v": 43}, {"u": 4,  "v": 91},
        {"u": 5,  "v": 81}, {"u": 6,  "v": 53},
        {"u": 7,  "v": 19}, {"u": 8,  "v": 87},
        {"u": 9,  "v": 52}, {"u": 10, "v": 48},
        {"u": 11, "v": 24}, {"u": 12, "v": 49},
        {"u": 13, "v": 87}, {"u": 14, "v": 66},
        {"u": 15, "v": 17}, {"u": 16, "v": 27},
        {"u": 17, "v": 68}, {"u": 18, "v": 16},
        {"u": 19, "v": 49}, {"u": 20, "v": 15}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "uscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "u"}
    },
    {
      "name": "vscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "v"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "vscale", "tickCount": 25},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "uscale"}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "area",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "orient": {"value": "horizontal"},
          "x": {"scale": "vscale", "field": "v"},
          "y": {"scale": "uscale", "field": "u"},
          "x2": {"scale": "vscale", "value": 0},
          "stroke": {"value": "#000000"},
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "update": {
          "interpolate": {"signal": "interpolate"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]